# How to edit commands in MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client on windows 10

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a solution where I don't need to use up and down arrow keys for editing commands. Previously, there used to be an edit command that opened an editor for editing. However, now I am finding no such command exist on my installed MySQL latest version. I installed MySQL in developer mode. Help command is not showing any edit or \e command.

Comment: Please do not post unnecessary images. The console supports copy/paste of text, which is  what you should use here whenever possible. Images should be used only when the problem cannot be demonstrated in any other way. For more information, see [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); the same reasons  apply here as well.

Comment: Removed image and I will keep this thing in my mind in future.

Comment: You might look at the *beta* release of MySQL Shell for VS Code as it does have the GUI editing you are requesting.  That or MySQL workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never knew the `edit` command existed up until now and tried it in my 5.7 , with no luck of course. Then I did a bit of research. Taken from mysql reference manual for 8.0: *MySQL Shell's \edit command (available from MySQL **Shell 8.0.18**) opens a command in the default system editor for editing, then presents the edited command in MySQL Shell for execution.* So I suppose you were using MySQL shell instead of the run-of-the-mill CLI launched by `mysql` command (or unlocked it in CLI after installing mysql shell). Please download it from MySQL community. The latest MySQL Shell 8.0.29 will do. Personally, I have not got round to trying mysql shell and probably won't do in the future, as I find workbench is too good to part with.